# Kernel function that is symmetric but not psd

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

My understanding is that kernels are psd - meaning that they are symmetric and have positive eigenvalues.

But, are there examples of a kernel that is symmetric and positive in the sense that $k(x,x') \geq 0$, but is not PSD? Or must all kernels be at least conditionally PSD?

Conversely, is there a kernel that is PSD but does not satisfy $k(x,x) \geq 0$ for all $x, x' \in \mathcal{X}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a kernel that is symmetric and nonnegative but not positive semidefinite, we just need a $2\times 2$ matrix $K$ with $K_{ij}\geq 0$ which is symmetric but has a negative eigenvalue. Consider 
$$
K = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has eigenvalues $\tfrac 12 (3 \pm \sqrt{17})$.

For a kernel that is symmetric and positive semidefinite but not nonnegative, we just need a $2\times 2$ matrix $K$ with $K_{ij}\not\geq 0$ which is symmetric but has a negative eigenvalue. Consider 
$$
K' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has eigenvalues $2,0$.